# Transposing rows into columns - clustered by Main_IDs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transpose, horizontallist

I am trying to figure out a way to transpose my data into rows grouped by specific clusters. I already ran a query which displays the data vertically but I wonder how I can transpose this.

Here is how my data after my query looks like (which I put into a temp table):

```
App  Old_Status_ID  New_Status_ID  Status_Change_Date  UserID
 A         1             2           2015_01_01         22
 A         2             3           2015_02_01         20
 A         3             4           2015_03_20         51
 B         1             2           2015_01_25         84
 B         2             3           2015_02_11         22
 C         1             2           2015_01_02         35
 C         2             3           2015_03_10         01
 C         3             4           2015_04_05         55
 ....
```

The abovementioned table has hundreds of different Apps, 7 different Statuses and hundreds of users.
What I am trying to do is to display all changes within the App just in one row. In addition, I want to include the difference of the elapsed time between the status changes in days (ΔStatus_Change_Date) = ΔSCD.

Here is an example of how the datasheet could like:

```
App Status1A Status1B User1 ΔSCP_1 Status_2A Status_2B User2 ΔSCP_2 ...
 A     1        2      22     0      2          3       20    31    ...
 B     1        2      84     0      2          3       22    17    ...
```

Unfortunately not everything fits into the row here but I hope that you will understand the concept and my goal with the example.

How can I transpose or write a query to achieve that the associated data from one App is in one row?

I really appreciate your help!!!

Here is some sample data:

```
    +-------+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------+
|  app  | OldStatusId | NewStatusId | StatusChangeDate | userid |
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------+
| 16195 |           1 |          32 | 2017-10-03       |   2137 |
| 16195 |          32 |          32 | 2017-10-03       |   2137 |
| 16195 |          32 |           8 | 2018-01-10       |   6539 |
| 16195 |           8 |           2 | 2018-01-12       |   3452 |
| 16505 |           1 |           1 | 2017-04-26       |   3551 |
| 16505 |           1 |          32 | 2017-05-24       |   2063 |
| 16505 |          32 |          32 | 2017-05-24       |   2063 |
| 16505 |           1 |           1 | 2017-06-23       |   3551 |
| 16505 |          32 |           4 | 2017-06-23       |   5291 |
| 16505 |           4 |          32 | 2017-06-26       |   2063 |
| 16505 |          32 |           8 | 2017-06-26       |   5291 |
| 16505 |           2 |           2 | 2017-06-28       |   3438 |
| 16505 |           8 |           2 | 2017-06-28       |   3438 |
| 16505 |           1 |          32 | 2017-08-28       |   2063 |
| 16505 |          32 |           4 | 2017-10-03       |   5291 |
| 16505 |           4 |          32 | 2017-10-04       |   2063 |
| 16505 |           2 |           2 | 2017-10-25       |   3438 |
| 16505 |           8 |           2 | 2017-10-25       |   3438 |
| 16505 |          32 |           8 | 2017-10-25       |   5291 |
| 16515 |           1 |          32 | 2017-06-01       |   2456 |
| 16515 |          32 |          32 | 2017-06-01       |   2456 |
| 16515 |           4 |           4 | 2017-07-25       |   5291 |
| 16515 |          32 |           4 | 2017-07-25       |   5291 |
| 16515 |           4 |          32 | 2017-07-27       |   2456 |
| 16515 |          32 |           4 | 2017-08-09       |   5291 |
| 16515 |           4 |          32 | 2017-08-10       |   2456 |
| 16515 |          32 |           8 | 2017-08-24       |   5291 |
| 16515 |           2 |           2 | 2017-08-28       |   3438 |
| 16515 |           8 |           2 | 2017-08-28       |   3438 |
| 16515 |           1 |          32 | 2017-10-06       |   2456 |
| 16515 |          32 |          32 | 2017-10-06       |   2456 |
| 16515 |           1 |           1 | 2017-10-17       |   2456 |
| 16515 |          32 |         128 | 2017-11-20       |   5291 |
| 16515 |          32 |           8 | 2017-11-29       |   5291 |
| 16515 |         128 |          32 | 2017-11-29       |   5291 |
| 16515 |           8 |           2 | 2017-12-07       |   3611 |
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: You can do this easily with conditional aggregation. If you need help with the code I would ask you to put together ddl (create table statements) and sample data in the form of insert statements.

Comment: Yes sure that would be awesome! FYI some status changes can skip certain stages like from 1 to 3 etc and some Apps might change status twice or so. In total I have 12K rows. Is that possible? What about pivot tables?

Comment: Again...I can help if you post some details.

Comment: @SeanLange Can I email you some sample data?

Comment: NO. Post it in your question. I am not a free consultant. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for the link. I included some sample data below my question. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have something in your real data you can use for ordering the rows? You can kind of use StatusChangeDate but you have some rows that were changed more than once on the same day. As such you can't ensure the order from the data posted. Once you solve that you can use a dynamic cross tab to accomplish this but I would question if this is worth the effort as some of these rows would have a LOT of columns.

Comment: I ordered by app, StatusChangeDate.  StatusChangeDate was initially a datetime which I converted into a date. I understand that there will be a lot of columns but what if we leave the ones out which don't change, meaning where the same value is in Oldstatus and NewStatus (OldstatusId = NewStatusID) ?

Comment: Right...look at the first two rows in your sample data. Ordering by StatusChangeDate is ambiguous, neither row is ensured to be first because they are both first.

Comment: Hey @SeanLange I actually took duplicated records and values out meaning I eliminated rows where OldStatusId = NewStatusID and then I partitioned by  app, newstatusid, oldstatusid, date , userid. As a result we would have a chronological order where statuschanges are unique which would mean that we don't need the tallytable, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave the ordering issue to you. As I stated previously when you have two rows with the same date you cannot know which row will be listed first because you don't have any way of doing that with your data. What you need here is some pretty ugly dynamic sql to generate all these columns. In this code I am going to use a tally table. In my system I keep this as a view. Here is the code for my tally table.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now we need to leverage dynamic sql and this tally table. We are going to have sql build our sql for us. Something like this.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    app int
    , OldStatusId int
    , NewStatusId int
    , StatusChangeDate date 
    , userid int
)

insert #Something 
(
    app
    , OldStatusId
    , NewStatusId
    , StatusChangeDate
    , userid
) VALUES

(16195, 1, 32, '2017-10-03', 2137)
, (16195, 32, 32, '2017-10-03', 2137)
, (16195, 32, 8, '2018-01-10', 6539)
, (16195, 8, 2, '2018-01-12', 3452)
, (16505, 1, 1, '2017-04-26', 3551)
, (16505, 1, 32, '2017-05-24', 2063)
, (16505, 32, 32, '2017-05-24', 2063)
, (16505, 1, 1, '2017-06-23', 3551)
, (16505, 32, 4, '2017-06-23', 5291)
, (16505, 4, 32, '2017-06-26', 2063)
, (16505, 32, 8, '2017-06-26', 5291)
, (16505, 2, 2, '2017-06-28', 3438)
, (16505, 8, 2, '2017-06-28', 3438)
, (16505, 1, 32, '2017-08-28', 2063)
, (16505, 32, 4, '2017-10-03', 5291)
, (16505, 4, 32, '2017-10-04', 2063)
, (16505, 2, 2, '2017-10-25', 3438)
, (16505, 8, 2, '2017-10-25', 3438)
, (16505, 32, 8, '2017-10-25', 5291)
, (16515, 1, 32, '2017-06-01', 2456)
, (16515, 32, 32, '2017-06-01', 2456)
, (16515, 4, 4, '2017-07-25', 5291)
, (16515, 32, 4, '2017-07-25', 5291)
, (16515, 4, 32, '2017-07-27', 2456)
, (16515, 32, 4, '2017-08-09', 5291)
, (16515, 4, 32, '2017-08-10', 2456)
, (16515, 32, 8, '2017-08-24', 5291)
, (16515, 2, 2, '2017-08-28', 3438)
, (16515, 8, 2, '2017-08-28', 3438)
, (16515, 1, 32, '2017-10-06', 2456)
, (16515, 32, 32, '2017-10-06', 2456)
, (16515, 1, 1, '2017-10-17', 2456)
, (16515, 32, 28, '2017-11-20', 5291)
, (16515, 32, 8, '2017-11-29', 5291)
, (16515, 128, 32, '2017-11-29', 5291)
, (16515, 8, 2, '2017-12-07', 3611)

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
    'with OrderedResults as
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by app order by StatusChangeDate) as RowNum
        from #Something
    )
    select app';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then OldStatusId end) as OldStatus' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
    + ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then NewStatusId end) as NewStatus' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
    + ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then StatusChangeDate end) as StatusChangeDate' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
    + ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then userid end) as userid' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
from cteTally t
where t.N <= 
(
    select top 1 Count(*)
    from #Something
    group by app
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)

declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from OrderedResults Group by app order by app';
declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;
exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```

The only part of this I did not demonstrate here is getting the change from row to row. You could do this with a temp table. But you would have to use a global temp table because the columns are being generated dynamically and the scope of the temp table would not let us view it after we execute the dynamic query. Once you understand what this code is doing you should be able to add the last part yourself. But if you get stuck post back and we will see what we can do.

Comment: Wow, that is pretty astonishing. I will work my way through your code and get back to you. Thank you very much for this great work.

Answer (score 0):

[Using PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a table-valued expression into another table. PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values that are wanted in the final output

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **STRING_AGG** function to achieve your goal.

Sample data:

```
create table clean (
  app VARCHAR(50),
  old_status INT,
  new_status INT,
  start_date DATETIME,
  end_date DATETIME,
  user_id INT
);

INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 2, 2, '9/12/2017 16:14:33', '11/1/2017 15:37:58', 3470);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 1, 2, '9/12/2017 16:14:33', '11/1/2017 15:37:58', 3470);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 2, 64, '11/1/2017 15:21:49', '11/1/2017 15:37:58', 3470);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 2, 2, '11/1/2017 15:37:58', NULL, 3470);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 64, 2, '11/1/2017 15:37:58', NULL, 3470);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 32, 8, '9/27/2017 10:19:48', '1/26/2018 10:50:18', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 32, 8, '1/26/2018 10:50:18', NULL, 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 1, 32, '9/13/2017 15:18:24', NULL, 5297);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 1, 1, '7/14/2017 14:29:51', '1/19/2018 14:15:13', 5327);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 1, 32, '1/19/2018 14:15:13', NULL, 5327);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 2, 2, '9/27/2017 10:40:06', '1/26/2018 10:52:54', 6509);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 8, 2, '9/27/2017 10:40:06', '1/26/2018 10:52:54', 6509);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14595', 8, 2, '1/26/2018 10:52:54', NULL, 6509);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 32, 4, '10/9/2017 14:28:10', '12/14/2017 14:45:59', 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 32, 4, '10/11/2017 11:57:05', '12/14/2017 14:45:59', 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 8, 8, '10/11/2017 15:02:23', '12/14/2017 14:45:59', 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 32, 8, '10/11/2017 15:02:23', '12/14/2017 14:45:59', 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 32, 4, '12/13/2017 10:51:30', '12/14/2017 14:45:59', 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 32, 8, '12/14/2017 14:45:59', NULL, 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 1, 1, '8/11/2017 12:17:49', '1/12/2018 16:06:16', 5298);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 1, 32, '9/19/2017 16:00:36', '1/12/2018 16:06:16', 5298);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 4, 32, '10/9/2017 15:45:59', '1/12/2018 16:06:16', 5298);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 4, 32, '10/11/2017 12:43:21', '1/12/2018 16:06:16', 5298);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 1, 32, '11/9/2017 16:05:44', '1/12/2018 16:06:16', 5298);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 32, 32, '11/9/2017 16:05:44', '1/12/2018 16:06:16', 5298);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 4, 32, '12/14/2017 10:38:19', '1/12/2018 16:06:16', 5298);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 1, 32, '1/12/2018 16:06:16', NULL, 5298);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 8, 2, '12/13/2017 13:36:56', '1/4/2018 16:47:43', 6506);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('14596', 8, 2, '1/4/2018 16:47:43', NULL, 6506);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 8, 2, '1/18/2018 16:11:46', '1/19/2018 10:27:44', 3441);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 8, 2, '1/19/2018 10:27:44', NULL, 3441);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 32, 8, '1/17/2018 11:11:40', '1/18/2018 10:22:32', 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 32, 128, '1/17/2018 15:54:36', '1/18/2018 10:22:32', 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 128, 32, '1/18/2018 10:22:28', '1/18/2018 10:22:32', 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 32, 8, '1/18/2018 10:22:32', NULL, 5290);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 1, 1, '10/1/2017 21:54:45', '12/27/2017 0:11:12', 5467);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 1, 32, '12/27/2017 0:00:18', '12/27/2017 0:11:12', 5467);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15980', 1, 32, '12/27/2017 0:11:12', NULL, 5467);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 1, 32, '6/1/2017 13:32:49', '12/12/2017 12:52:16', 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 32, 32, '6/1/2017 13:32:49', '12/12/2017 12:52:16', 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 4, 32, '7/24/2017 9:51:27', '12/12/2017 12:52:16', 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 4, 32, '7/27/2017 13:26:39', '12/12/2017 12:52:16', 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 4, 32, '8/10/2017 13:19:22', '12/12/2017 12:52:16', 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 1, 32, '10/6/2017 13:43:21', '12/12/2017 12:52:16', 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 32, 32, '10/6/2017 13:43:21', '12/12/2017 12:52:16', 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 1, 1, '10/17/2017 12:51:12', '12/12/2017 12:52:16', 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 1, 32, '12/12/2017 12:52:16', NULL, 2456);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 8, 2, '8/18/2017 13:26:22', NULL, 3438);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 2, 2, '8/18/2017 13:26:22', NULL, 3438);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 2, 2, '11/10/2017 13:15:40', NULL, 3611);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 8, 2, '11/10/2017 13:15:40', NULL, 3611);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 4, 4, '7/21/2017 11:19:39', '11/10/2017 12:20:50', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 32, 4, '7/21/2017 11:19:39', '11/10/2017 12:20:50', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 32, 4, '7/25/2017 13:15:59', '11/10/2017 12:20:50', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 4, 4, '7/25/2017 13:15:59', '11/10/2017 12:20:50', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 32, 4, '8/9/2017 16:36:43', '11/10/2017 12:20:50', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 32, 8, '8/10/2017 13:46:16', '11/10/2017 12:20:50', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 32, 128, '11/7/2017 16:42:24', '11/10/2017 12:20:50', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 128, 32, '11/10/2017 12:20:43', '11/10/2017 12:20:50', 5291);
INSERT INTO CLEAN VALUES('15998', 32, 8, '11/10/2017 12:20:50', NULL, 5291);
```

query:

```
with a as (
    select app, user_id,
    old_status, new_status, 
    start_date, end_date, datediff(day, start_date, end_date) as delta 
    from clean
), b as (
    select app, user_id,
    old_status, new_status, 
    start_date, end_date, ISNULL(delta, 0) as delta
    from a
    where old_status != new_status
), c as (
    select app, user_id,
    concat('[', old_status, '-', new_status, ' ', delta, ' days]') as column_2
    from b
), d as (
    select c.app, concat('{USER: ', c.user_id, ' ', STRING_AGG(c.column_2, ' | '), '}') as concat
    from c
    group by c.app, c.user_id
)
select d.app, STRING_AGG(d.concat, '; ') as user_activity from d
group by d.app
order by d.app;
```

result:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  app  | user_activity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 14595 | {USER: 3470 [1-2 50 days] | [2-64 0 days] | [64-2 0 days]}; {USER: 5291 [32-8 121 days] | [32-8 0 days]}; {USER: 5297 [1-32 0 days]}; {USER: 5327 [1-32 0 days]}; {USER: 6509 [8-2 121 days] | [8-2 0 days]}
| 14596 | {USER: 5290 [32-4 66 days] | [32-4 64 days] | [32-8 64 days] | [32-4 1 days] | [32-8 0 days]}; {USER: 5298 [1-32 115 days] | [4-32 95 days] | [4-32 93 days] | [1-32 64 days] | [4-32 29 days] | [1-32 0 days]}; {USER: 6506 [8-2 22 days] | [8-2 0 days]}
| 15980 | {USER: 3441 [8-2 1 days] | [8-2 0 days]}; {USER: 5290 [32-8 1 days] | [32-128 1 days] | [128-32 0 days] | [32-8 0 days]}; {USER: 5467 [1-32 0 days] | [1-32 0 days]}
| 15998 | {USER: 2456 [1-32 194 days] | [4-32 141 days] | [4-32 138 days] | [4-32 124 days] | [1-32 67 days] | [1-32 0 days]}; {USER: 3438 [8-2 0 days]}; {USER: 3611 [8-2 0 days]}; {USER: 5291 [32-4 112 days] | [32-4 108 days] | [32-4 93 days] | [32-8 92 days] | [32-128 3 days] | [128-32 0 days] | [32-8 0 days]}
```

In case the order of changes and the order of users is important here is a second solution with **WITHIN GROUP** clause:

```
with a as (
    select app, user_id,
    old_status, new_status, 
    start_date, end_date, datediff(day, start_date, end_date) as delta 
    from clean
), b as (
    select app, user_id,
    old_status, new_status, 
    start_date, end_date, ISNULL(delta, 0) as delta
    from a
    where old_status != new_status
), c as (
    select app, user_id, start_date,
    concat('[', old_status, '-', new_status, ' ', delta, ' days]') as column_2
    from b
), d as (
    select c.app, concat('{USER: ', c.user_id, ' ', STRING_AGG(c.column_2, ' | ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.start_date ASC), '}') as concat
    from c
    group by c.app, c.user_id
)
select d.app, STRING_AGG(d.concat, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.concat ASC) as user_activity from d
group by d.app
order by d.app;
```

result:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  app  | user_activity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 14595 | {USER: 3470 [1-2 50 days] | [2-64 0 days] | [64-2 0 days]}; {USER: 5291 [32-8 121 days] | [32-8 0 days]}; {USER: 5297 [1-32 0 days]}; {USER: 5327 [1-32 0 days]}; {USER: 6509 [8-2 121 days] | [8-2 0 days]}
| 14596 | {USER: 5290 [32-4 66 days] | [32-4 64 days] | [32-8 64 days] | [32-4 1 days] | [32-8 0 days]}; {USER: 5298 [1-32 115 days] | [4-32 95 days] | [4-32 93 days] | [1-32 64 days] | [4-32 29 days] | [1-32 0 days]}; {USER: 6506 [8-2 22 days] | [8-2 0 days]}
| 15980 | {USER: 3441 [8-2 1 days] | [8-2 0 days]}; {USER: 5290 [32-8 1 days] | [32-128 1 days] | [128-32 0 days] | [32-8 0 days]}; {USER: 5467 [1-32 0 days] | [1-32 0 days]}
| 15998 | {USER: 2456 [1-32 194 days] | [4-32 141 days] | [4-32 138 days] | [4-32 124 days] | [1-32 67 days] | [1-32 0 days]}; {USER: 3438 [8-2 0 days]}; {USER: 3611 [8-2 0 days]}; {USER: 5291 [32-4 112 days] | [32-4 108 days] | [32-4 93 days] | [32-8 92 days] | [32-128 3 days] | [128-32 0 days] | [32-8 0 days]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks like everything is in one column but I can theoretically go insert it to excel and choose the appropriate delimiter to split it up.